# make command not working in NS 2.35

Tags: linux, network-programming, makefile, ns2

I am trying to modify AODV routing protocol using NS 2.35. I have made some changes to the files aodv.cc and aodv.h. Now, to apply these changes I have run a **make** command inside ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35 folder and getting the following error message:

```
In file included from aodv/aodv_logs.cc:31:0:
./aodv/aodv.h:53:18: fatal error: list.h: No such file or directory
 #include <list.h>
              ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [aodv/aodv_logs.o] Error 1
```

How will I solve this?

Comment: This is in no way related to [tag:make]

Answer (score 1):

---

`#include <list.h>` is ignored in a default ns2.

If changes are made, the non existing 'list.h' can sometimes be called.

You can comment it out : `// #include <list.h>`

---

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <list.h>
```

add this code to aodv.cc