# dsr/linkcache .cc: fatal error: list.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, network-programming, ns2

I am using NS2.35 and Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

I want to run DSR using link cache.

I uesd "make" to recompile NS2. I got the following error:

```
dsr/linkcache .cc: fatal error: list.h: no such file or directory.
```

I used locate list.h and this is its directory

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29/include/linux/list.h
```

That means the header file exists

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: The file `list.h` is being included in another file, and it isn't in your
include path.  You need to find the correct file and make sure it's added to
your include path when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

---

ns2 : Old files. The gcc 2.95 header `list.h` is included in a couple of files. And is simply ignored in a stock ns2, when g++ is later than version 3.x :

`list.h` is also present in gcc 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 : `/usr/include/c++/3.4.6/backward/list.h`

Besides that, a similar question is answered here [make command not working in NS 2.35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798689/make-command-not-working-in-ns-2-35)

---

Comment: when I comment  ` #include <list.h>` make doesn't work. It gives another error  `dsr/linkcache.cc:233:0: warning: "INFINITY" redefined [enabled by default]
./routing/route.h:47:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
dsr/linkcache.cc:439:58: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of ‘bool LinkCache::findRoute(ID, Path&, int)’ [-fpermissive]
dsr/linkcache.cc:193:7: error: after previous specification in ‘virtual bool LinkCache::findRoute(ID, Path&, int)’ [-fpermissive]
make: *** [dsr/linkcache.o] Error 1`  which version of gcc should I use?

Comment: »» error: default argument given for parameter 3 of ‘bool «« : Don't know, it's a bug in your unknown code ......

Comment: I am using ns2.35. The code of dsr/linkcache.cc  exists at ns2.

Comment: The error appears as a linkcache.cc error. But is caused be some changes in another file.